# Django and mozilla_django_oidc - how to log out of session?

Tags: python, openid, openid-connect

I have successfully integrated a Django test application with our Okta IAM service, using the `mozilla_django_oidc` package. Now I can log in using Okta, which is just cool.

But now I want to log *out* of the session again - which I cannot do it seems. `mozilla_django_oidc` provides three URLs basically:

- `name=oidc_authentication_callback`
- `name=oidc_authentication_init` (the one [used for the "Login" link](https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#add-login-link-to-templates))
- `name=oidc_logout`

Naively I just added that code to my application, and expected a working logout:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <p>{{ user.email }} - <a href="{% url 'oidc_logout' %}">Logout</a></p>
{% else %}
  # etc.
{% end %}
```

The problem is: The `logout` endpoint only takes POST requests.

Now, how can I log out of the session?

Answer (score 4):

I used this trick to solve the problem

File settings.py

```py
OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT = "https://{...}/auth/realms/{...}/protocol/openid-connect/logout"
OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_URL_METHOD = "main.openid.logout"
```

I created a file openid in main folder with method logout

main.openid.py

```py
logout_endpoint = import_from_settings("OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT", "")
return logout_endpoint + "?redirect_uri=" + request.build_absolute_uri("/")
```

And I created a view LogoutView inherited from OIDCLogoutView

view.py

```py
class LogoutView(OIDCLogoutView):
    def get(self, request):
        return self.post(request)
```

And finally

urls.py

```py
path('logout', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')
```

So when i use logout method in my http link (GET Method), it will redirect to OIDC_OP_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT that will redirect to home of current site